# Python hexadecimal string to integer conversion error

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, hex

I'm trying to port [this library](https://github.com/gardhr/finabel) from Javascript to Python, but keep getting a strange error in my attempt to convert a hexadecimal string to integer. It works fine for short strings, but for some reason chokes on larger ones:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16:
> '14fdbc5ade9e3d4097f421fe7b4b54ad05883d589c3b3f6648b5e0ea2b64b359158087b793b859a4c51af0fd8c1edb7a92b8d5843c1a2d659929357c7e1869784435d6dcfd8d29b619194333b38655493eb4eb3deeffbf339e91c7c0f6113b4bb6672f49'

The code looks like this:

```
def stretch(value):
    hexadecimal = hex(value)[2:]
    buffer = hexadecimal
    while True:
        buffer += record_separator + hexadecimal
        if len(buffer) >= minimum_digits:
            break
    return int(buffer, 16)
```

Comment: If you just want to convert the string to decimal the use value = int(string, 16). Python 3 has no limit on it's integer value. Your string result in 546755182137531943293891170863886409257177002102958031106970218913938945216495276608761007929774380907079475078176395384371438944791022503587328767282546555465705414556027853888426781796298321719051075009856267471199860627126795651319803721

Comment: Okay, so this may just be a compatibility issue then. Invoking 'python --version', I get 'Python 2.7.17'.

Comment: Yep, wrong version. Works just fine on Python 3. If you'd like to post that as an answer I'd gladly accept it as solved. And thanks for the timely response.

Comment: You're welcome. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 has no limit on it's integer values.

So you can use int(hex_string, 16) to convert even large strings to an integer value.

```
s = '14fdbc5ade9e3d4097f421fe7b4b54ad05883d589c3b3f6648b5e0ea2b64b359158087b793b859a4c51af0fd8c1edb7a92b8d5843c1a2d659929357c7e1869784435d6dcfd8d29b619194333b38655493eb4eb3deeffbf339e91c7c0f6113b4bb6672f49'

s_int = int(s, 16)

print(s_int)
```

Result

```
546755182137531943293891170863886409257177002102958031106970218913938945216495276608761007929774380907079475078176395384371438944791022503587328767282546555465705414556027853888426781796298321719051075009856267471199860627126795651319803721
```